# Is this an F# structured printf bug?

Tags: .net, f#, printf

Code:

```
printfn "%10s"  "abc"
printfn "%-10s" "abc"
printfn "%10d"   123
printfn "%-10d"  123
printfn "%10c"   'a'
printfn "%-10c"  'a'
```

Output:

```
       abc
abc
       123
123
a
a
```

So right aligning `%c` does not work as I expect...

`F# 2.0 build 4.0.30319.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that the fact that it is missing in the table of valid types is causing the issue (the "%c" modifier is definitely supported, because the type of `printfn "%c"` is `char -> unit` as you would expect). So, it does look like a bug to me.

An easy workaround is to use the "%O" modifier which takes any type (also including `char` values) and formats it using `ToString` method (avaliable for all .NET types):

```
> printfn "%10O" 'a';;
         a
val it : unit
```

---

BTW: I looked at the F# library source code (from the CTP release) and here is the relevant bit from `printf.fs` (line 478):

```
| 's',nobj::args -> 
  formatString outputChar info width (unbox nobj) false; i+1,args
| 'c',nobj::args -> 
  outputChar (unbox nobj); i+1,args // (1)
| 'b',nobj::args -> 
  formatString outputChar info width 
    (if (unbox nobj) then "true" else "false") false; i+1,args
| 'O',xobj::args -> 
  formatString outputChar info width 
    (match xobj with null -> "<null>" | _ -> xobj.ToString()) false; i+1,args
```

The line (1) formats a character and it ignores the `width` parameter (which is the width you specified). So, unless this is (for some reason, e.g. performance?) intended behavior, it really feels looks a bug!

I suppose that the following implementation would fix the problem (*Brian ;-)! Are you there?*):

```
| 'c', nobj::args -> 
  formatString outputChar info width 
    (string ((unbox nobj):char)) false; i+1,args
```

Answer (score 3):

%c isn't listed in the [table of valid types for F# printf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Maybe that's the cause of your problem.

Quite strange, according to the table there isn't a type to print single characters at all.